# install two different versions of Visual Studio in the same computer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2008

I have Visual Studio 2013 in my computer and i need Visual Studio 2008 can i download it without any problems?
 Because my university is using visual studio 2008.

Comment: Should be fine.  Do you encounter any problems when you try?

Comment: They can work side-by-side. Note however that in the past I have experienced problems when installing an older VS edition *after* the newer version. A re-install of the newer version was needed to make it work well again. It's been a while and maybe this no longer applies to installing 2008 after 2013.